# Thread safe processing

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have an algorithm that recognizes objects in photos. The main problem is that it is not thread safe, so e.x. when you set a new configuartion or when you start processing a new image while there is still processing difference one, the algorithm's behavior is undefined and may crash. Below I put my code and my implementation that didn't work well.

```
// config struct
public struct Config {} 

// reslut of the algorithm
public struct Product {}  

// algorith class
public class Recognizer { 
   func apply(config: Config)
   func process(frame: UIImage) -> Product {
       let prodcut = Product()
       return prodcut
   } 
}

// protocol for an object interested in the result of the Recognizer
protocol Observer: class {
    func didProcess(frame: UIImage, prodcut: Prodcut) 
}

// protocol that wraps Recognizer class
protocol RecognizerService {
    func add(observer: Observer)
    func remove(observer: Observer)
    var recognitionConfig: Config { get set }
    func process(frame: UIImage)
}
```

Below how it looks now.

```
let recognizerQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

class HumanFaceRecognizer: RecognizerService {
      var recognitionConfig: Config
      var observers: [Observer]
      let algorythm: Recognizer
      private var recognizerQueue: DispatchQueue

      init(recognitionConfig: Config,
           observers: [Observer] = [],
           recognizerQueue: DispatchQueue,
           algorythm: Recognizer) {
           self.recognitionConfig = recognitionConfig
           self.observers = observers
           self.recognizerQueue = recognizerQueue
           self.algorythm = algorythm
      }

      func add(observer: Observer) {
          observers.append(observer)
      } 

      func remove(observer: Observer) {
          observers.remove(observer)
      }

      func process(frame: UIImage) {
          recognizerQueue.async { [weak self, currentFrame = frame, currentConfig = recognitionConfig] in
          self?.algorythm.process(frame: currentFrame)
          observers.forEach { $0.didProcess(frame: currentFrame, result: currentConfig) }
      }
}
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with dispatching this computation to background, but I can't find right solution to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you provided is not sufficient to get a clear answer to your problem. It would be helpful if you posted some call stacks of your crashes etc.

First thoughts are:

- Maybe the observers are not capable of being called from an arbitrary thread (global queue), because they perform some UI updates etc. In this case, you could call `didProcess` from the main queue.
- Maybe there is a problem that some observers remove themself from the `HumanFaceRecognizer` while they are called in `didProcess`, i.e. the `forEach` call works on a modified collection. In this case, you should copy the observers array before traversing it.
- You could also try to (deep) copy the algorithm class, to make it "more" thread safe

Hope this helps a little :-)